# Values changed of event_scheduler in Group Parameter are not reflecting in Aurora Database

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-aurora-serverless

I have configured an Aurora Serverless DB, I need to setup Event scheduler in it, But after updating the values of "event_scheduler" in the parameter group, this values is not appearing in the Global Variables. while the value of "event_scheduler" need to be marked as "ON" for execution of Event Scheduler.

I am using aurora5.6 Family for Parameter Group values, and Aurora MySQL as DB Engine.

Comment: What is the result of `show global variables like 'event%';`?

Comment: it is returning false, even i have updated the Parameter group values

Comment: I have the same issue and I am thinking that it is probably a limitation when using serverless. I could not find in the docs or elsewhere that it is an actual limitation though. https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/01/04/amazon-rds-aurora-mysql-differences-among-editions/

Answer (score 0):

I confirmed by starting a fresh new serverless instance tied to a parameter group with event_scheduler=ON that serverless instances are just ignoring this parameter. So it is another limitation when using Aurora Serverless, but not documented in the docs.